# Python to Split folders into subfloders when we reach 100mb

Tags: python, subdirectory

All ,

I am trying to find best way to use Python to split folders into sub folders such that each sub folder is within 100mb.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What have you tried and how did it differ from what you expect? Show some code, ask a specific question about the code, and SO can help.

Comment: Why, what is the ultimate goal? And what happens if a single file is over 100MB?

Comment: So ultimate goal is to ingest files to a system that only accepts folders less than 100mb. If individual files are over 100 then we just skip them. Basically I am looking best way to creat sub folders of equal size 100mb

Comment: "Basically I am looking best way to creat sub folders of equal size 100mb" that's the classic knapsack problem. What is your actual question though? What have you tried so far? Post your code, even if it doesn't work.